# transfer data from localstorage to same php file and recall data to variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have data in localStorage and POST successfully to the self php file using ajax as code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cartID = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("magiohang"));
console.log("your cart ID is:"+cartID);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>",
  data: {cartID: cartID}, 
  success: function(data){alert("data transfered successfully")}  
  });
</script>
```

then I want to recall this data to a variable inside this php file so that I can send it to my email. Code as below:

```
<?php
$name = "";
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
if (isset($_POST["cartID"])) {
  $name = $_POST["cartID"];
}
echo $name."\n";
$values = json_decode($name);
echo "your cartID is: ".$values."\n";
?>
```

I test it in inspect view there is no error message but the variable $name doesnot have recalled data. Please help me to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: how have you verified that `$name` does not have the data? your php code does an `echo`, but you never check the returned data in `success: function(data){...}`

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to go to that file after the ajax request. That creates a new instance of your php script and there is no post then. Also note you are not sending JSON to back end so json_decode doesn't make much sense

Comment: My question is still there without any answer that I really need.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing the JSON.stringify call on your data:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>",
      data: JSON.stringify({cartID: cartID}),
      success: function(data){alert("data transfered successfully")}  
  });
```

Comment: JSON.stringify is not necessary on `data`, as according to the docs - [`It is converted to a query string, if not already a string`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Do this and OP needs to modify back end code also. Seems pointless